# Count the posts from post table from a perticular post ID

Tags: wordpress

I have a project post type. I want to count all post from the table. But there is a condition. I want to put a number(Post ID).

Like i have 10 posts from project post type. Here is i print the post IDs.

1, 2, 8, 11, 12, 15, 20, 21, 22, 25

I want to count the posts from 20(Post Id) post. It means it should give the answer 3. Because there are three posts after post 20( Post Id ). 21, 22,25.

I have tried with wp_query offset. It did not work Because offset is taking taking number of post not the post ID.

Thank you. Waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `post__in` parameter and feed a `range` as value. `range()` returns an array of values, exactly what `post__in` needs

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'project', // Your custom post type name
    'post__in' => range( 21, 1OO ), // Set end to any integer value
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'fields' => 'ids' // Only get post ID's 
];
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
echo $q->found_posts;
```

Comment: I got 10 in the query, but i have only one post. How can i get the exact post count.

Comment: As `posts_per_page` is set to `1` and the `fields` parameter to `ids`, the query will return only one post ID (*performance trick if you just need post count*). `found_posts` holds the count of posts that matches the query as a whole without the `posts_per_page` parameter. This is what `WP_Query` uses to calculate offsets for pagination and pagination as such. If `found_posts` says `10`, then 10 posts matches the query.

Comment: But it is general to get 1 post if i set to 'posts_per_page' => 1 in the args.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, in the sample code, use `echo $q->post_count;`, that will give you the exact amount of posts returned by the query.

Comment: I have copied your code and tried, But it did not work. You know, what is the problem in your code ? You have wrote 'post_in' instead of 'post__in'. So that it has given the wrong answer. Please correct that, otherwise i have tried the post_count instead of found_posts.

Comment: O crap, sorry about that. I am posting from a mobile so I cannot test my code. Thanks for letting me know about the error. I have corrected that. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to count the post use `$wpdb` instead of `WP_Query` because WP_Query loads [wp_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) object.

```
global $wpdb;
$count = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT count(*) from $wpdb->posts WHERE id > 21")
```

Read more on `$wpdb` [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Column)

Comment: I think it is not good to use $wbdb, if you have wp_query option.

Comment: @Ranjit `WP_Query` loads each post object which is `wp_post` as mentioned in this answer, the question was to count the from 21. If you only want to count posts from table then why not use `$wpdb` instead of WP_Query unless you also want to display posts on frontend ?